# How to Install Solr to use with Haystack in Django

Tags: django, tomcat, solr, tomcat7, django-haystack

I'm installing Solr to be used with Haystack / Django.

How do I go about installing Solr? Do I need to follow the online instructions exactly and install services like Tomcat?

Comment: what environment are you running this in? OS: Linux, MacOS, Win? Dev or Production? and versions you are interested in.

Comment: I'm running it on windows. I'm using it in development for now but intend to go to production within a few days. I don't care for a version (as long as it works) but I downloaded the latest at the moment

Comment: then I would suggest a hosted solution like websolr. it starts at like 20/mo which is super affordable considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above questions I just commented make all the difference if you are set on installing / setting this up yourself. OR you could use a **hosted service** (read: easy).

Try out http://websolr.com I'm loving it.

If you are on **OSX** and want a local Solr instance just to try out for some development, this is an awesome tutorial: http://realityloop.com/blog/2011/07/19/setting-multicore-apache-solr-os-x-using-homebrew
essentially `brew install solr`, and then some configuration.

If you are trying to do a **production** level solr server on a **linux** operating system, I would suggest working with an instruction set specific to that distribution and the version you are using. OR even better, bite the bullet and pay someomne who knows what they are doing to set it up (make sure your indexes won't fail or go down).